# UPDATE table IF data in another

Tags: mysql, update, timeout, data

I would like to retrieve some data from another table and put it in my first table.

I used this query:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET table_1.firstname = 
(
  SELECT 
    firstname 
  FROM table_2 
  WHERE table_2.lastname = table_1.lastname LIMIT 1
);
```

But this request timed out because I have almost 300k lines in `table_1`

I tried to update only one field in one record as follows:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET table_1.firstname = 
(
  SELECT 
    firstname 
  FROM table_2 
  WHERE table_2.lastname = "toto" LIMIT 1
);
```

But I got: `ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

I was wondering if my request could be more efficient and faster?

Edit_1:
I can't exactly put the structure of the tables but I represented it with the examples I'm using in my query:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: table_1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `table_1` (
  `lastname` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lastname`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: table_2
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `table_2` (
  `lastname` varchar(9) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(14) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`firstname`),
  KEY `lastname` (`lastname`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think there is another problem because even when I don't loop over the 300k lines I'm getting a timeout.

Here the numbers of records in table_1 : 260905 and in table_2: 32,165124

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please give us  the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_x\G` for your two tables! Also the no. of records in each table. 380k isn't a very large table - there may be something else going on!

Comment: Do not use correlated subqueries. Study multiple-table UPDATE syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using a correlated subquery, as Akina mentioned, it probably causes a scan operation to occur against your entire table (which is 32,165,124 rows if I read that correctly). You're better off writing the query in a more relational manner which can be achieved with an `INNER JOIN`, for example such as this:

```
UPDATE table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
  ON table_1.lastname = table_2.lastname
SET table_1.firstname = table_2.firstname
```

The `INNER JOIN` will only produce a result set where the data exists in both tables for the fields being joined by in the `ON` clause. Therefore only the rows that exist in `table_2` and match `table_1` by `lastname` will be used for the `UPDATE` and may result in a more efficient seek operation.

Comment: Thank you all, this one works perfectly ! I'm gonna study more the multiple-table update !